# Android Fragment filling radiogroup

Tags: android, android-fragments

For a reason no elements get changed and some do not.

A Fragment called QuestionFragment is in an Action called QuizAction.
The fragment gets replaced in the `OnCreate` of the Action.
In the fragment I try to add radiobuttons and change text but all fail.
All text that involves "it works" do work and do change the fragment elements.
All text tot involve "it does not work" do not change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

personally: I guess it has to do with the first fragment declared in the xml file of the activity that is actually edited but the second one does not. The one that I should see but never actually do. I also do not know how to check this.
Anyhow this is my code.

In OnCreate of the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    if (manager == null) manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray("Possible Ansers", PossibleAnsers);
    args.putSerializable("protocol", p);
    fragment = new QuestionFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    ft= manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment).commit();
}
```

In the onViewCreated of the QuestionFragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String[] antw = new String[0];
    rg = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.smallTekst);
    tv.setText("works");
    if(bundle != null) {
        if( bundle.getStringArray("PossibleAnsers") != null) {
            antw = bundle.getStringArray("PossibleAnsers");
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < antw.length; i++) {
        addRadioButton(c, rg, "radiobutton "+i +"that doesn't work");
        Toast.makeText(c, "rdm toast that works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tv.setText("Doesn't work");
    }
    addRadioButton(c, rg, "working radioButton");
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Already a big thanks.

Comment: where did you set the "mogelijkeAntwoorden" argument?

Comment: Just forgot to translate to english. I think it is visible now.